# INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST in User.LanguageLocaleKey only from apex code

Tags: apex, user, language, invalid

I'm having a problem creating an user in apex code. I am assigning the user the Catalan language, and it gives me an invalid value error.

```
10:03:28.1 (29921169)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2228]|this.LanguageLocaleKey|"ca"|0x2ca810a4
10:03:28.1 (29927760)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2230]
10:03:28.1 (30123981)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2236]|this.TimeZoneSidKey|"Europe/Madrid"|0x2ca810a4
10:03:28.1 (30131174)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2237]
10:03:28.1 (30134327)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2237]|Bytes:5
10:03:28.1 (30203592)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2237]|this.LocaleSidKey|"es_ES"|0x2ca810a4

10:03:28.1 (31437928)|DML_BEGIN|[2263]|Op:Insert|Type:User|Rows:1
10:03:28.1 (31460934)|LIMIT_USAGE|[2263]|DML|1|150
10:03:28.1 (31472075)|LIMIT_USAGE|[2263]|DML_ROWS|1|10000
10:03:28.1 (31489718)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
10:03:28.1 (48941531)|DML_END|[2263]
10:03:28.1 (49045429)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[2263]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Idioma: valor inapropiado para el campo de lista de selección restringida: ca: [LanguageLocaleKey]
10:03:28.1 (49701210)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2263]|Bytes:197
```

The strange thing is that we have existing users with the same configuration, and in fact if I import (with the inspector) a user exactly identical to the one I try to insert by code, I don't get any type of error.
Another strange thing, is that when i insert it by code, it throws the error even before executing the trigger. Inserting it by import, it launches the trigger as usual.
Some idea?

Comment: Language support is closely tied to the API version.What is the API version of apex class you are creating?

Comment: Is 40.0, i will try to set to one more recent.

Comment: Sir, you are my savior. I love you. It was the version. I'm going to raise an altar for you

Comment: So happy I could help :) Posted this info as an answer so it can help others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, Language support is closely tied to the API version. Switching to the most latest API version of apex class would help fix the issue.

From [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5),

> NOTE Language support is closely tied to the API version. For example, we introduced support for Belgian Dutch (nl_BE) in API version 40.0. To take advantage of this language, you must use API version 40.0 or later. In general, we recommend using the most recent version of the API to make the most of our language features.